# UIPath and desktop Application

Tags: uipath

I would like to automate a process between excel and a desktop application . It will feed data from the excel to the application. Is UIpath the right tool to use or is there a better tool.?? Please help. I have programmming experience and ready to learn a new tool. I do not know which tools in Rpa are availble and whats the best way to go forward.

Comment: UiPath could be a proper solution for you. But just saying, such open questions are not suitable here. Please only ask for a specific task on StackOverflow. So in your case you should first go for the UiPath Academy. Because your task is easy.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
**Yes**

*A slightly longer answer.*
UiPath is be a great tool for this - there is a free community version as well.
As an alternative, you could take a look at MS Power Automate Desktop.

Both tools a build specifically for the use case you describe.

So pick one and go ahead and start :)